# system-config-samba won't run in 17.04

Tags: samba

Trying to run system-config-samba on 17.04 (it worked fine for me on 16.10), here is terminal output:

```
main1@system1:~$ gksu system-config-samba
  File "/usr/sbin/system-config-samba", line 45, in <module>
    mainWindow.MainWindow(debug_flag)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.samba_data = sambaParser.SambaParser(self)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/sambaParser.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.parseFile ()
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/sambaParser.py", line 225, in parseFile
    token = self.createToken (line, section) 
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/sambaParser.py", line 310, in createToken
    name, value = line.split ("=", 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
main1@system1:~$
```

I do not know what this means, nor how to fix the problem.  I've searched, but found nothing.  (Although, I am not sure of the correct search terms to use.)

I do not see my question as a duplicate of [Where is the Samba configuration GUI in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785877/where-is-the-samba-configuration-gui-in-ubuntu-16-04) .  That question is asking where system-config-samba is located.  I already have system-config-samba installed, and I am able to find it with no problem.  Also, that question is discussing how to install samba, which I have already done, I have verified that smbd and nmbd are running.  Finally, that question does not at all discuss the exact, same error messages that I show above, which is exactly what I am asking about.

I am hoping someone can help me with understanding these messages and fixing it so system-config-samba works.  Thanks.

Comment: Please look at the answer by user55108...

Comment: I'm still not seeing the connection, I'm afraid you're going to have to very plainly lay it out for me.  In user55108's response, he discusses error messages different from mine.  Then, he abandoned trying to use system-config-samba.  His final sentence is this:  "So, bottom line, system-config-samba doesn't seem to work "out of the box" on ubuntu 16.04".  The wording of that seems deliberately very non-authoritative to me.  Are you saying that you KNOW that system-config-samba cannot/will not work in 17.04, and so I should stop trying to get it to work?  I just want to clearly understand you.

Comment: The error message implies that, somewhere in your Samba configuration you have a line that should be `something=somethingelse` and you have omitted the `=` sign.

Comment: waltinator, I think you are correct.  After posting this question, out of desperation I did alter smb.conf.  I made a number of changes, so I do not know EXACTLY which change(s) solved the problem, but system-config-samba works now.  Thank you.  I will add, though:  Now knowing that the problem was likely the "syntax" of smb.conf, I don't see how this question can be considered a duplicate - Which question is it duplicating that provided the response of fixing smb.conf?  Sincere question, I don't know which question it is a duplicate of.